# Debug Assertation Failed - Dont find bad code

Tags: c++, class, copy-constructor

i have writen one class to get used to C++. When i try to delete the Object the debugger throws a "Debug Assertation Failed" with _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse).

Maybe somebody can show me my mistake in debugging all memory addresses seams fine.

**Lines.h**

```
#ifndef LINES_H
#define LINES_H
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Lines
{
public:
    Lines(int _laenge) : fuellzeichen{ '#' }, name{ "Hans-Peter" }, laenge{ _laenge }{};
    Lines(int _laenge, char _fuellzeichen) : fuellzeichen{ _fuellzeichen }, laenge{ _laenge }, name{ "Hans-Peter" }{};
    Lines(int _laenge, char _fuellzeichen, char* _name) : fuellzeichen{ _fuellzeichen }, laenge{ _laenge }, name{ _name }{};
    Lines(const Lines& _l);
    ~Lines();
    Lines& operator= (const Lines & _l);
private:
    char fuellzeichen;
    int laenge;
    char* name;
};


#endif // LINES_H
```

**Lines.cpp**

```
#include "Lines.h"

Lines::Lines(const Lines& _l){
    fuellzeichen = _l.fuellzeichen;
    laenge = _l.laenge;
    int len = strlen(_l.name) + 1;
    name = new char[len];
    strncpy(name, _l.name,len);
}
Lines& Lines::operator=(const Lines& _l){
    if (this == &_l){
        return *this;
    }
    Lines tmp(_l);
    swap(fuellzeichen, tmp.fuellzeichen);
    swap(name, tmp.name);
    swap(laenge, tmp.laenge);
    return *this;
}
Lines::~Lines(){
    delete[] name;


}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "Lines.h"

    int main(int argv, char* args[]){
        Lines a(20,'#');
        Lines b(a);
}
```

Comment: Replace `char *name` with `std::string` and all your problems will disappear. You don't need to define your own copy constructor, assignment operator or destructor any more.

Answer (score 2):

**Do not `delete []` what you did not `new []`!**

```
Lines(int _laenge) : fuellzeichen{ '#' }, name{ "Hans-Peter" }, laenge{ _laenge }{};
Lines(){ delete[] name; }
```

Take a look at the above two lines:

- The ctor points `name` to the string-literal `"Hans-Peter"`.
- The dtor `delete []`s whatever `name` points to.

---

The easiest and best remedy is using a `std::string` instead of doing your own memory-management.
That would also allow you to follow the rule-of-zero instead of the rule-of-3.

There is one other *bug*, or at least bug-waiting-to-happen: Your one-argument-ctor should be `explicit`, so it is not considered for implicit conversions.

As an aside, consider using default-arguments to simplify your code.
Also, use `const` where appropriate:

```
explicit Lines(int _laenge, char _fuellzeichen = '#', const char* _name = "Hans-Peter")
        : fuellzeichen{_fuellzeichen}, laenge{ _laenge } {
    int len = strlen(_name)+1;
    name = new char[len];
    memcpy(name, _name, len);
};
```

As you are using copy-and-swap for assignment, consider writing the free-function `swap` and passing by value:

```
Lines& Lines::operator=(Lines _l) { swap(this, &_l); return *this; }
void swap(Lines& a, Lines& b) {
    using std::swap;
    swap(a.fuellzeichen, b.fuellzeichen);
    swap(a.name, b.name);
    swap(a.laenge, b.laenge);
}
```

(`~Lines` and `operator=` should probably be defined in the class, and `swap` must be declared in that header.)

Comment: Removed downvote- you expanded on your answer after I downvoted + commented.